# MATLAB: find connected component by pixel location in binary image

Tags: matlab, binary, components, line

I have a binary image which I used bwconncomp and regionprops on to divide into regions of interest. I have a line of pixels which I want to lay across the binary image...and find which region of interest/connected component has the most line pixels in it. So in the attached image I use bwconncomp on bwimage, I get components 1,2,3. Then I have a list of pixels corresponding to the blue line. I want to find which connected component has the most of the blue line in it (#1).

I imagine its something like...

```
line=(some pixel values);
cc=bwconncomps(bwimage);
tempvar=[];

for i=1:length(bwconncomps)
     tempvar=find(cc.PixelIdxList{i}==line);
end

[~ answer]=max(tempvar);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ismember`  to determine how many items in `PixelList` occur in your list of pixels that lie along the line. Then you can use `max` to identify the component that has the most.

```
% Indices of pixels that are along the line of interest
linePixels = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]  

% Determine the number of pixels within each component that are on this line
nPerComponent = cellfun(@(inds)sum(ismember(inds, linePixels)), {cc.PixelIdxList});

% Find the component with the most points on this line
[~, answer] = max(nPerComponent);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this working: "index exceeds matrix dimensions". The cyan was just to illustrate my question-in reality i have just the binary image and then an index of values for the line-these are in the same format as bwconncomps PixelIdxList (i.e. in a 200x200 pixel image the first pixel in the second column would be "201" not "1,2")

Comment: I'm still getting the error "input #2 expected to be cell array, was double instead"...sorry probably simple solution but I'm missing it

Comment: if i do num2cell(cc(i).PixelIdxList) this seems to work on a component by component basis-which works fine in a for loop, can't get this to work on the full CC.PixelIdxList though...

Comment: @user3470496 What version are you using? I've updated with a version that should work now.